Why Test MSE is better than Validation MSE?
I am working on time series transformers.
I Have ran code of PatchTST(time series transformer) for etth1  multivariate data set but, I see test loss is always better than validation loss and I have also looked at Infomer (time series transformer)it was also doing same.
EarlyStopping counter: 12 out of 100
Updating learning rate to 4.048376602284338e-09
Epoch: 100 cost time: 1.73805832862854
Epoch: 100, Steps: 63 | Train Loss: 0.4116055 Vali Loss: 0.9261471 Test Loss: 0.4135703
EarlyStopping counter: 13 out of 100
Updating learning rate to 3.643538942055904e-09
>>>>>>>testing : 336_192_PatchTST_ETTh1_ftM_sl336_ll48_pl192_dm16_nh4_el3_dl1_df128_fc1_ebtimeF_dtTrue_Exp_0<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
test 2689
mse:0.41365155577659607, mae:0.4210711419582367, rse:0.6107578277587891


I think it may be due to Data distribution mismatch. Try to split the data using Stratified sampling.

I saw several models on time series they were all doing same thing. I am just running their libraries I am matching with their results. but same validation loss is more than test. they were all accepted papers.

If the time series has strong seasonality, the test set might fit these patterns better than the validation set.
The fact that this behavior is observed across multiple accepted papers suggests that it might be a characteristic of these models or the datasets rather than a mistake. However, it's crucial to ensure that the evaluation process is rigorous and free from any form of data leakage or bias.
also sometime it happens that some architecture perform good with certain kind of pattern and with other it fails. if you think you have done all things correct then write the paper.

Do you think its due to hardware? they might have run on different AWS machine, I was using google Colab GPU.

No, GPU architecture may affect the model accuracy but it will be negligible.

So is it a common scenario to be like this? When running Transformers on Time series data.

No, its a case of data leakage. This situation is unusual and often indicates a problem in the model development or evaluation process. Typically, we expect:
,Training MSE to be the lowest, Validation MSE to be higher than Training MSE, Test MSE to be similar to or slightly higher than Validation MSE

How can this be true for all the models? every model I have tested I have same scenario, but they were producing the exact numbers (MSE and MAE) they were publishing in their papers.
